# Using bm with eulervm gives inconsistent ‘<’ and ‘>’ characters

Tags: math-mode, bold, bm, eulervm

I prefer to use `bm` package to bold math. However, I noticed that when used with `eulervm`, this gives inconsistent results for ‘<’ and ‘>’ characters.

I wonder what causes it and can the usage `bm` be fixed to get proper ‘<’.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

    \texttt{\hphantom{mathbold}\llap{bm}}: \quad $ 1 + 1 < 3; \quad \bm{1 + 1 < 3} $

    \texttt{mathbold}: \quad $ 1 + 1 < 3; \quad \mathbold{1 + 1 < 3} $

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Exciting problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an inconsistency in the shape of `<` and `>` in the `zeurm10` and `zeurb10` fonts used for the symbols with `eulervm` active:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
bm: & $1 + 1 < 3$; $\bm{1 + 1 < 3}$ \\
mathbold: & $1 + 1 < 3$; $\mathbold{1 + 1 < 3}$
\end{tabular}

{\usefont{U}{zeur}{m}{n}\symbol{"3C}}

{\usefont{U}{zeur}{b}{n}\symbol{"3C}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\mathbold`, which is a math alphabet selection, only letters and numbers become bold, but not other symbols.

You can work around the inconsistency by using Computer Modern for the `<` and `>` symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{cmletters}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{<}{\mathrel}{cmletters}{"3C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{>}{\mathrel}{cmletters}{"3E}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
bm: & $1 + 1 < 3$; $\bm{1 + 1 < 3}$ \\
mathbold: & $1 + 1 < 3$; $\mathbold{1 + 1 < 3}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the important point being: **It's not my fault**

Comment: please take a closer look -- the result in the last example still isn't the same with `\bm` and `\mathbold`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Of course they aren't the same: `\mathbold` is a math alphabet switch, which doesn't act on symbols such as `<`.

Answer (score 7):

`\mathbold` is math alphabet command (like `\mathbf`, `\mathit` etc) so it has no effect on `<` .  `\bm` though does affect `<` and you get the character that the package sets up for `\boldmath`, If you add

```
\boldmath

 $ 1 + 1 < 3\showlists$
```

You will see that `\bm` is selecting (in normal math) the fonts used in `\boldname`.

In this case that is

```
....\U/zeur/b/n/10 <
```

But as you show the bold font's `<` is a rather different shape to the medium weight font

So this appears to be a font issue.